# Remove All Padding/Borders/Margin

Tags: html, css

First of all, I know we have a thousand questions on this, but I do believe I went through just about everything relevant and tried it. In short, I have a simple html page with a body, which contains a table, which contains 2 rows, each row has two cells. I remove all padding, margin, and borders with the exception where I account for border diameter in setting width/height. Goal is to print a 4x3" label for something, which is what the body size is set to in mm.

tl;dr: Why do I still have padding?

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.noMarginBordersPadding{
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPEKba

[image]

P.S. If you hit print, there is also mysterious whitespace on the bottom, below the border, but I don't want to dilute the question too much.

Comment: Side note, you can omit the units when the value is `0` (i.e. `padding: 0; margin: 0; border: none;`)...

Comment: Was familiar with that, but it's a good thing to know for people reading it later. There still seems to be whitespace on the right hand side after the border collapse solution, but I think it's due to me setting the width poorly. Still, I wish I understood what collapsing borders truly does when they are already zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the [`border-collapse` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) for the table. The default value is `separate`:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: That did it, will accept when countdown ends, thank you. Do you know why by any chance? I have zero borders set on the table, table cells, and table rows. Why did this help?

Comment: Because by default the browser sets the value on that property to separate which gives your table the extra spacing.

Comment: I understand that - I have used border-collapse before. E.g. without it, two adjacent table cells with borders set 1px and 1px would have a cumulative 2px border between them. Whereas with collapse, it would be 1px. However, 0+0=0. You did answer my question, this would just be the icing on the cake.